# What is the difference between Plain Text and text view on android studio 3.0.1?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, user-interface

Was trying to design a user interface for my apps login screen activity. Was wondering how the textview and Plain text differed (for ex in their attributes and functionality) and the implications of choosing one over the other.

Comment: textview is to show some kind of text to user , plainText  is editText which is used to take input from user (example login details)

Answer (score 34):

**Plaintext** is nothing but the **Edittext**. It has changed the name in **Android studio** but if you check into Design view you will get to know that it still has name of **Edittext** only.

**Usages**

**Textview**  : should be used for uneditable text which user wants to read but not to manipulate. e.g. News, Articles, Blogs.

**Plain text/ Edittext** : should be used for taking user input in alphanumeric form. e.g. UserId, Comments.